# Text not displaying the variable I am sending to it

Tags: flutter, text, datepicker, messagebox

I am trying to develop a small application to learn Dart and Flutter.
Right now, I have one view with with an icon. When I click on this icon, I get an alert box with a date picker.
I select a date, and after a click on a OK Button, I am supposed to get back to the previous view.
On the first view, I have a Text widget. this one is supposed to display the Date selected previously.
My issue is that the Text widget does not display the right date. I have tried to add a setState to the text widget, but I am getting an error.

Please, see the code source bellow.
Many thanks.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'cupertino DatePicker.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

var myselectedDate;

class AddProject extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _AddProjectState createState() => _AddProjectState();
}

class _AddProjectState extends State<AddProject> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formState = GlobalKey<FormState>();

var gender;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    String projectName = "";
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Add Project",
        ),
          
          actions: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Icon(
                Icons.save,
                size: 26.0,
              ),
            )
        ),
        ]
    ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(

          child: Icon(
            Icons.send,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            //if (_formState.currentState.validate()) {
            //  _formState.currentState.save();

            //  Navigator.pop(context, true);
            }
          //}
            ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Form(
            child: Column(
              children: [

                //Field : Type project Name
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 1.0),
                  child: TextFormField(

                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Project Name"),
                    maxLength: 200,
                    maxLines: 2,

                    validator: (value) {
                      return value.isEmpty ? "Project name cannot be empty" : null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      projectName = value;
                    },
                  ),
                ),

                //Start Date text
                Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 18.0, 8.0, 1.0),
                      child: Text("Start Date",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),),
                    )

                ),

                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(1.0, 5.0, 8.0, 10.0),
                      child: IconButton(
                        splashColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),//Image.asset('assets/icons/tag.png',
                        //height: 30.0, ),

                      //=============================

                        onPressed: () {
                          showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return StatefulBuilder(
                                  builder: (context, setState){
                                    return AlertDialog(
                                      title: Text('Choose Date'),
                                      content: DatePickerDemo(),
                                      actions: <Widget>[
                                        FlatButton(
                                            child: Text("Cancel",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.grey,)),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              //selectedContext=false;
                                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                            },
                                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))

                                        ),

                                        FlatButton(
                                          child: Text("OK",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.blue,)),
                                          onPressed: () {

                                            myselectedDate=  DateFormat('dd MMMM, yyyy').format(selectedDate);


                                             print  ('test=' + myselectedDate.toString());

                                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  });
                            },
                          );
                        }

                      //=============================
                    ),),


                    Text('test=' + myselectedDate.toString()),
                  ],

                ),

                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            key: _formState,
          ),


        ],
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import '09_project_add.dart';

//var mySelectedDate = selectedDate;
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

class DatePickerDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DatePickerDemoState createState() => _DatePickerDemoState();
}

class _DatePickerDemoState extends State<DatePickerDemo> {
  /// Which holds the selected date
  /// Defaults to today's date.


  /// This decides which day will be enabled
  /// This will be called every time while displaying day in calender.
  bool _decideWhichDayToEnable(DateTime day) {
    if ((day.isAfter(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1))) &&
        day.isBefore(DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 10))))) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  _selectDate(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    assert(theme.platform != null);
    switch (theme.platform) {
      case TargetPlatform.android:
      case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        return buildMaterialDatePicker(context);
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
        return buildCupertinoDatePicker(context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "${selectedDate.toLocal()}".split('/')[0],
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 55, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => _selectDate(context),
              child: Text(
                'Select date',
                style:
                TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  buildCupertinoDatePicker(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext builder) {
          return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height / 3,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: CupertinoDatePicker(
              mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
              onDateTimeChanged: (picked) {
                if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
                  setState(() {
                    selectedDate = picked;
                    myselectedDate = selectedDate;
                  });
              },
              initialDateTime: selectedDate,
              minimumYear: 2020,
              maximumYear: 2125,
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  buildMaterialDatePicker(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2125),
      initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.calendar,
      initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
      selectableDayPredicate: _decideWhichDayToEnable,
      helpText: 'Select booking date',
      cancelText: 'Not now',
      confirmText: 'Book',
      errorFormatText: 'Enter valid date',
      errorInvalidText: 'Enter date in valid range',
      fieldLabelText: 'Booking date',
      fieldHintText: 'Date/Month/Year',
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light(),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setState in the correct place. Here is there:

```
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
         myselectedDate=  DateFormat('dd MMMM, yyyy').format(selectedDate);
      });

      print('test=' + myselectedDate.toString());
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    },
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried, but the Text Widget  Text(  myselectedDate.toString()), is still not displaying the last date selected in the picker. I have tried to use setState with the Text Widget, but I am getting an error about a Void function "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used"
setState(() {
                      Text(  selectedDate.toString())
                      }),